# how to SELECT values WHERE userId is js typeof uuid

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I am querying a database where userId is a UUID.

To get cat_name I'm passing UUID value as a JavaScript string.

I am testing using Postman and

If I have userId value with no quotes in the url it works.

> http://localhost:8080/api/catDb/11d6af03-20ac-4f04-a21c-28ec418a2c18

If I save the same value as a variable in postman it returns [] or from my java script it fails with a (404) not found alarm.

I've tried casting to a UUID, but it alarms with

```
 error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "'11d6af03-20ac-4f04-a21c-28ec418a2c18'"
     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
     at Parser.handlePacket (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
     at Parser.parse (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
     at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {   length: 170,   severity: 'ERROR',   code: '22P02',   detail:
 undefined,   hint: undefined,   position: undefined,  
 internalPosition: undefined,   internalQuery: undefined,   where:
 "unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'",   schema: undefined,   table:
 undefined,   column: undefined,   dataType: undefined,   constraint:
 undefined,   file: 'uuid.c',   line: '134',   routine:
 'string_to_uuid'
```

Here is my table

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS public.category(
    id Serial not null unique,
    userID uuid not null,
    cat_name varchar(100) unique not null,
     primary key(id),
     foreign key(userID) references public.user(id)
);
```

Here is my query end point

```
const express = require('express')
const { response, request } = require("express")
const router = express.Router();
const app = express()
const { Pool } = require('pg');

//GET all categories
router.get('/:userId', async (request, response) => {
    const userId = request.params.userId

    try{
    await pool.query('SELECT  cat_name FROM category WHERE userId::text = $1;', [userId], (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        };
        response.status(200).json(result.rows);
    })}
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

How could the quotes be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated
Any additional information required will be provided

Comment: Try replacing `userId::text` with `userId` (just a wild guess)

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisG for the suggestion, but no dice. I did save a variable without quotes in Postman and instead of text I cast userId as UUID and it worked, but I am still not getting that response when I post from other backend code